# How can I make a math question generator that gives 3 digit addition questions and single digit multiplication questions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In this code, I am basically trying to create a math question generator, where I want the question generator to randomize between addition subtraction, and multiplication. As of now, I have a code that allows me to create problems that are just single digits, how can I make it so the addition and subtraction questions are 2-3 digits and multiplication is only one digit? (I am new to JavaScript so it is a little bit confusing to me)

I.e. 202+305 = 507
*next question*
2x4=8

So on and so forth.

Here is the code that I have until now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="11question"></div>
    <input id="answer" />
    <button id="check" onclick="check()">Check</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    var operations = {
      '+': function (num5, num6) {
        return num5 + num6;
      },
      '-': function (num5, num6) {
        return num5 - num6;
      },
      x: function (num5, num6) {
        return num5 * num6;
      },
    };
    var accans;

    newquestion();

    function newquestion() {
      document.getElementById('answer').value = '';
      document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      var num5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      var num6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      var operationChosen = ['+', '-', 'x'][
        Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))
      ];
      accans = operations[operationChosen](num5, num6);
      document.getElementById('11question').innerHTML =
        num5 + operationChosen + num6;
    }

    function check() {
      answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
      if (accans == answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
      } else if (accans != answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
      }
    }
  </script>
  '
</html>
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) From that link: "Answerable questions don't ask how to implement a feature, they ask how to accomplish a programming task (among other things)." In other words, your question needs to be more focused rather than asking how to add a whole feature to your program.

Comment: pick the operator first, then based on the operator, generate the random numbers between a certain range which you want for that operator

Answer (score 1):

You can define a range by `getRandomInt`. [Check out here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

**Live Demo:**

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

var operations = {
'+': function (num5, num6) {return num5 + num6;},
'-': function (num5, num6) {return num5 - num6;},
'x': function (num5, num6) {return num5 * num6;}
}
var accans

newquestion()

function newquestion() {
document.getElementById('answer').value = "";
document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "white";

var operationChosen = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
if (operationChosen == 'x') {
    var num5 = getRandomInt(0,10);
  var num6 = getRandomInt(0,10);
}
else {
    var num5 = getRandomInt(10,1000);
  var num6 = getRandomInt(10,1000);
}
accans = operations[ operationChosen ]( num5, num6 )
document.getElementById("11question").innerHTML = num5 + operationChosen + num6;
}

function check() {
answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
if (accans == answer) {
    document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
}
else if (accans != answer) {
    document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="11question"></div>
<input id="answer">
<button id="check" onclick="check()">Check</button>
```